# I am working with Tk inter and yahoo_finance

Tags: python, tkinter, yahoo-finance

I want to write a program such that I can enter in a pop-up entry box the stock symbol of my choice:

I know how to create an entry box in TKinter generally, but I don't know how to employ the .get() method here:

```
import datetime
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.finance as finance

root = Tk()
E1 = Entry(root, bd=8)
E1.pack(fill=Y)
root.mainloop()
startdate = datetime.date(2013,1,1)
today = enddate = datetime.date.today()
ticker = 'I WANT THIS TO COME FROM THE ENTRY BOX '?
fh = finance.fetch_historical_yahoo(ticker, startdate, enddate)
```

Comment: I believe it's as easy as `ticker = E1.get()`though you might want to add a button to trigger the get call

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use [StringVar](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm). For example

```
import datetime

import tkinter

from tkinter import *

import matplotlib.finance as finance

root = Tk()    

# create a StrringVar
ticker_entry_var = StringVar()

E1 = Entry(root, bd=8, textvariable=ticker_entry_var)

E1.pack(fill=Y)

root.mainloop()

startdate = datetime.date(2013,1,1) 
today = enddate = datetime.date.today()

# get value from the entry box 
ticker = ticker_entry_var.get()
print(ticker)
```

Now, when you close the tk window, ticker will have the value from the stringvar.